# Sketch the quantum logic gates correctly and give a proof for the identity

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-phase-estimation

If I denote by $U^c$ the controlled version of the quantum operation $U$ 
$$U^c=|0\rangle \langle 0|\otimes \mathbb{1}+|1\rangle \langle 1|\otimes U$$

1. I can first apply $U^c$ and afterward measure the control qubit.
2. Or I can first measure the control qubit and then apply $U$ only if
   the    measurement outcome was 1.

This is a trick to save qubits when performing quantum phase estimation.
I tried to sketch this with quantum logic gates - I am not sure if I did it right.

[image]

Now I want to show that these two methods give the same result.

1. \begin{align*}
   &\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle + |1\rangle)U^c|\Psi\rangle\\
   &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle + |1\rangle)(|0\rangle \langle 0|\otimes \mathbb{1}+|1\rangle \langle 1|\otimes U)|\Psi\rangle\\
   &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle \langle 0|0\rangle\otimes 1 + |1\rangle \langle 1|0\rangle \otimes U +|0\rangle \langle 0|1\rangle\otimes 1 +|1\rangle \langle 1|1\rangle \otimes U)|\Psi\rangle\\
   &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle \otimes 1 + |1\rangle \otimes U)|\Psi\rangle
    \end{align*}

   I hope my calculations are correct.
2. Now I can say, this is the same as measuring the control qubit and if it is $|1\rangle $ I calculate $|1\rangle \otimes U |\Psi\rangle$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These two circuits produce the same results - in both cases you'll get $|0\rangle \otimes |\psi\rangle$ with 50% probability or $|1\rangle \otimes U|\psi\rangle$ with 50% probability.

---

But I don't think this is going to help you with the phase estimation algorithm. In quantum phase estimation application of $U^c$ is followed by inverse Fourier transform before the measurement is done.

Let's take a look at how QPE works for the case of 1 control qubit if we know that the eigenvalue of $U$ is either $+1$ or $-1$ (i.e., the phase estimated is either 0 or 0.5). We can use the $Z$ gate as $U$ to make our calculations more specific.

The inverse QFT for 1 qubit is just the Hadamard gate, so the circuit for QPE looks as follows:

[image: Quantum phase estimation for Z gate]

You can check that the measurement result will be 0 if the second qubit starts in the $|0\rangle$ state and 1 if it starts in the $|1\rangle$ state - which allows you to estimate the phase you're looking for.

The circuits you started with give you a 50-50 chance of measuring 0 or 1 on the first qubit regardless of the starting state of the second qubit, and thus do not help you estimate the phase.

Comment: It does help with phase estimation. This trick is called the semi-classical Fourier transform.

Comment: @DaftWullie Thank you for your answer. In a standard implementation I would initialize, apply hadamard Gate, perform controlled evolution, perform inverse FT and then i would measure (like in Mariias figure). What will change in my implementation if i want to use the above trick to implement a single-qubit phase estimation? Do i need to apply a final Hadamard Gate after inverse FT and then measure the qubits.

Comment: @Suslik Apply Hadamard gate, measure that qubit. Apply phase gates (rotations same as angles of the controlled-gates) on the target qubits. See https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9511007

Comment: Thank you for the paper.

Comment: @DaftWullie I didn't know that, thank you for correcting me!